# Suppose the worker in Exercise 6.3 pushes downward at an angle of 30 below the horizontal

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work

The following question is from University Physics chapter 6 exercise 6.4. I have attempted this problem multiple times but get it wrong because I keep using the wrong angle. The problem specifically mentions that the applied force is at an angle below the horizontal. Which I assume to be -30 degrees. However, the correct solution comes from using positive 30 degrees. Here is the example of the resulting free-body diagram:

Why is the angle positive and not negative? Why can I not use -30 or 330 degrees?

[image: Free-Body diagram]

Comment: Suppose the worker in Exercise 6.3 pushes downward at
an angle of 30 below the horizontal. (a) What magnitude of force
must the worker apply to move the crate at constant velocity?
(b) How much work is done on the crate by this force when the
crate is pushed a distance of 4.5 m? (c) How much work is done on
the crate by friction during this displacement? (d) How much work
is done on the crate by the normal force? By gravity? (e) What is
the total work done on the crate?

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. You have not stated what the problem is, only the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By drawing the applied force in the direction as shown in your FBD you have already taken care of the fact that the force is in a downward direction.

If you want to use the angle (with sign) to define the direction of the force your FBD should look like this.

[image]

Here you have $\vec F = \cos \theta \,\hat x + \sin \theta \, \hat y$

What you havve done is to say that $\theta$ is negative ie is actually $-\theta$ where the numerical value of $\theta$ is positive.

Then $\vec F = \cos (-\theta) \,\hat x + \sin (-\theta) \, \hat y = \cos \theta \,\hat x - \sin \theta \, \hat y$ and used this relationship to draw your FBD.